# Removing mail-stack-delivery doesn't remove its components

Tags: apt, uninstall, email, postfix, dovecot

Once I installed `mail-stack-delivery`

```bsh
$ sudo apt-get install mail-stack-delivery
```

I decided I wanted something else, so I tried to uninstall it

```bsh
$ sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove mail-stack-delivery
```

Despite doing that, I still can issue following commands (which are a part of the `mail-stack-delivery` bundle):

```bsh
$ postfix
$ dovecot
```

Did I do something wrong? Should I uninstall every individual package manually? If so, are there any other packages bundled with  `mail-stack-delivery` other than `postfix` and `dovecot`?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, the correct command is:

```bsh
$ sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove mail-stack-delivery
```